# Синхронизация Model и ViewModel, когда приложение - Client

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день.

## Предыстория

Используя паттерн MVVM столкнулся с тем, что Model, который обычно считается DTO и в примерах то же самое, в моем случае больше подходит на Domain Model(или если быть точнее интерфейс, между Domain Model и Интерфейсом. Строиться архитектура На шаблоне Clean Architecture). С этим Domain Model работают и другие. По сути приложение на WPF является клиентом.

## Вопрос

### Проблема:

При таком подходе Model должна давать знать ViewModel об изменениях в себе.
Исходя из MVVM напрямую она это делать не может, поэтому использовать можно способы:

1. (Не рекомендуется)Реализация у Model интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged и потом
   синхронизация из ViewModel(ViewModel этим занимается, Model просто
   предоставляет инструмент для этого)
2. Использовать ObservableCollection в Model и в ViewModel и последующая синхронизация. Зачем связать 2 коллекции? Во View все равно ViewModel отдавать.

### Сам вопрос:

**Т.к я выбрал способ 2, то как мне синхронизировать 2 коллекции?**

Первое, что пришло в голову - использовать интерфейс IModel(название сущности), вынести его отдельно. Создать коллекцию ObservableCollection в Model, при создании VM получать ссылку на эту коллекцию с тем же интерфейсом и View пусть View работает через интерфейс с этой коллекцией. Тем самым я не синхронизирую 2 коллекции, а оставляю одну. Для реализации подобного в Model есть DataModelController, который является синглотоном, который занимается хранением и выдачей данных. В итоге ViewModel через Di получает от этого DataModelController эту коллекцию.

Почему так? Логически все круто, View не знает о Model(знает об интерфейсе IModel), Model не зависит от ViewModel(классы Model реализуют просто интерфейс).

Но тут начинаются проблемы, если ViewModel несколько сложнее, чем просто переопределение Model. Допустим появляются команды, разная логика у самого ViewModel классов. Придется юзать (ViewModel)IModel, что ведет за собой приведение, что ведет за собой создание нового объекта при приведении(потому что так это работает), что ведет за собой разсинхронизацию(которую можно частично решить путем того, что при приведение сохраняется ссылка на Model(IModel точнее).

Думал еще создать абстрактный класс и чтобы Model и ViewModel наследовали его, тогда при приведении(вроде) это будет один и тот же объект, просто под разным соусом.

Также можно построить иерархию интерфейсов IViewModel:IModel. Тогда это будут тоже один и тот же объект под разным соусом. Но тогда, возможно, будет не очень хорошо с точки зрения поддержки. Да и глубокая иерархия наследования интерфейсов ничем не лучше иерархии наследования классов. Да и встает так же вопрос поддержки этого другими, ибо вроде это не популярно. Тобишь встает вопрос поддержки не мной.

Намного легче для понимания синхронизация двух коллекций.

**Update 2**

Уточню вопрос путем примеров и самих уточнений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на картинке, Model может изменяться не только Client'ом, но и сервером. Т.е может Client2 тоже сидит и следит за сервером.

Один из сценариев: Client1 отправил изменения на Server, Server сохранил данные отправил всем подписчикам(Client2). Далее по схеме. Данные проходят через ServieCommunicationController и попадают в Model. Model должен неявно уведомить ViewModel. ViewModel обновляет View. И наоборот. Model на Client является синхронизирующийся с Server слоем.

Comment: Не понял, почему 2 - не рекомендуется, а 3 - ок? По сути 2 и 3 - это частные случаи 1

Comment: Кстати, 2 и 3 не исключают, а дополняю друг друга, ведь если у вас изменилось одно из свойств модели, то `ObservableCollection` (`INotifyCollectionChanged`) ничего об этом не скажет, как и не скажет `INPC` о том, что коллекция, в которой этот элемент лежит изменилась (добавился новый объект/удалился/переместился)

Comment: Посмотрите готовые решения, `Catel` например.

Comment: @Андрей поэтому объекты, которые находятся в ObservableCollection и должны реализовать INPC, чтобы уведомить об изменениях данных. Да, вы правы. Это частные случаи первого способа, но в первом скорее нужно будет самом реализовать весь механизм связывания.Его стоить убрать

Comment: @VladD а что вы думаете? Очень интересует ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После недели поисков и проб, пришел к выводу, что:

1. Вариант 1 из вопроса будет работать, но будет сложно поддерживать и чисто архитектурно не каноничен никак.
2. Второй способ работает прекрасно, его я и реализовал, но к несчастью оказалось(вполне логично, зачем тогда INPC) ObservalableCollection при вызове события CollectionChange не реагирует на изменение свойств объектов коллекции.Для такого поведения есть BindingList, но она работает, только если INPC используется)).
3. Адекватный вариант номер один: нарушить каноничность и сделать в модели событие ModelUpdate, который реагирует только на свои свойства(не на коллекции внутри) и привязать VM. Нарушает каноничность, но уже лучше, чем INPC.
4. Адекватный вариант номер 2: не нарушая каноничности, говорить, успокаивая себя, "Модель записывает свое состояние" вместо "Вызов события для обновления VM". Тогда применяя вариант номер 3(или DomainEvent), модель и правда ничего не знает о VM, не знает она так же о сервере(ибо это событие вызывает ServiceCommunicationController и его MessageHandler при обновлении Model). VM же в созданной во время копаний SynchronizedObservalableCollection будем подписываться на обновление состояния Model и будет брать обновление примено как в ответе @RusArt

Вариант номер 4 я буду использовать и напишу, как все прошло.

Comment: Модель в любом случае не знает про VM. Реализация INPC !="знание о VM". INPC же плох тем, что кидает событие на каждое изменение, а не только в конце "мы тут все поменяли, вот теперь можешь читать изменения",

Comment: Ну, дело в том, что если бы не было бы VM, то и INPC бы не юзался. В каком то смысле "Мы использует INPC , чтобы связь модель и VM".

Comment: А без INPC или другого трекинга измененного свойства как вы собираетесь сказать VM (или кому другому) что именно изменилось? Или пусть вид все перерисовывает?

Answer (score 1):

Ваши вопросы слегка философские, разные люди вам ответят по-разному. Отвечу из личного опыта:

1. Программы где Модель реализует INPC для нужд ViewModel в итоге становились сложно поддерживаемыми, сложно тестируемыми. Их приходилось переписывать.
2. Пишу модели так, как будто других слоев не существует. Модель содержит как базовые объекты, так и бизнес-логику. Пишу тесты на модель.
3. Сам факт того, ViewModel требует реализации INPC в модели уже говорит мне о том, что пора что-то менять. Изменение модели чаще всего является ответом на действие пользователя, то есть происходит из ViewModel. Может ли модель изменится другим путем, кроме как из ViewModel? Если да, то в модели должно быть соответствующее событие. Но чаще это не так. А раз ViewModel знает, что что-то произошло, зачем ждать реакции изменения с нижнего слоя, если можно просто запросить новое состояние измененной модели? Модель должна быть сама по себе.
4. Как организовать коммуникацию между несколькими ViewModel, не затрагивая при этом модель? Я знаю несколько вариантов:

   - Изменять модель через сервис. Сервис имеет событие, на которое можно подписаться другим ViewModel.
   - Сервис сообщает контроллеру, что надо обновить какие-то ViewModel.
   - Использовать паттерн [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**Ответ на конкретно ваш вопрос.**

Так как вашего кода нет, придумаю свой. Заиспользуем гипотетический EventAggregator. Подписываемся на некое глобальное событие, которое вызывает изменение модели.

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private Model _model;

    public Model Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set
        {
            _model = value;
            UpdateValues();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateValues()
    {
        Values.Clear();
        Values.AddRange(_model.Values);
    }

    public ViewModel(Model model, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _model = model;
        eventAggregator.Subscribe<SomeProcessExecuted>(OnProcessExecuted);
    }

    private void OnProcessExecuted(object data)
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

Comment: И что там сложно поддерживать в 1. И в какую сторону переписывать 1? 3 очень спорно

Comment: @vitidev Представьте себе модель, где объекты являются сущностями EntityFramework. И они реализуют INPC. VM изменяет сущность, сущность по сути оповещает другие VM (выполняет роль контроллера VM). Это явное нарушение принципа единственной ответственности. А иногда эти VM еще в ответ на изменение сущности меняют что-то еще. В какой-то момент уследить за всем становится нереально.

Comment: Не понял вашего примера. VM не оповещает другие VM. Сущность изменяется (причина не имеет значения) и изменения отображаются на всех VM что следят за этой сущностью. Это обычные подписчики. Где тут нарушение SRP? Проблема разве что в избытке событий.

Comment: @vitidev да, избыток событий. Притом данные могут измениться не просто "Добавился эллеменов", но и "Изменилось значение". Можно через события, но есть готовые средства. Просто нужно ими правильно воспользоваться

Comment: @RusArt Почти то, что надо. Только у меня обновление в 2 стороны и со стороны сервера приходят только изменения, поэтому коллекцию так нельзя пересоздавать. Притом во View все будет скакать. Даже есть грамотно вызывать OnPropertyChanged(или как там), то у пользователя будет скакать все(нажал ComboBox для выбора, а тут все обновилось. Перерисовалось все, потому что не элементы и коллекция изменилась, а просто появилась новая коллекция)

Comment: @vitidev тобишь вариант 2 и 3 - это нужная абстракция над 1

Comment: @RusArt насчет агрегатора. Да, вариант неплохой. Только Model должна затрагиваться. Поэтому стоит(возможно) подписать на один агрегатор все нужные ViewModel и Model(притом в обе стороны). Но по сути я так и хотел сделать, просто не знал про такой термин, а придумал сам и описал подобные в моих словесных примерах.

Comment: @Arantler там 100500 вариантов и ни один из них не является лучшим. Я плохо понял вашу проблему, но вот вам еще один термин для гугления Domain Events, хотя по факту все оно одно и то же, только под разными углами.

Comment: @Arantler, вы вот говорите, что обновления приходят с сервера, а как они приходят? Кто сообщает что данные обновились и их надо запросить заново?

Comment: @Arantler Почему бы контроллеру коммуникаций не сообщить VM что им надо обновить свои модели?

Comment: @Андрей все по факту происходит. Сервер отправляет данные на клиент, он их обрабатывает через спец handler , который делает дела на клиенте(записывает данные в DataModelControlerService). Далее обновляется View

Comment: @RusArt как вариант, но есть удобный механизм биндинга, который это и будет делать.

Comment: @RusArt а как VM будет обновлять модели при изменении допустим одного свойства без модели с INPC? Полностью перечитает сущность и будет дергать все свои INPC для вида?