# Методы оптимизации Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

По мотивам своего вопроса [Синхронизация Model и ViewModel, когда приложение - Client](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723762/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-model-%D0%B8-viewmodel-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-client)

Наткнулся на Reactive Extensions. Этот подход(и набор инструментов) заточен на решение моего вопроса, но меня смущает производительность этого решения.

**Вопрос:**

Какие существуют методы оптимизации Reactive Extensions в С#(на уровне организации архитектуры и на уровне кода)?

Comment: А зачем их оптимизировать? Какую проблему вы решаете?

Comment: @VladD как раз таки ссылка на вопрос в моем вопросе - это та самая проблема. 
Перефразирую: есть же определенные подходы, при которых Reactive Extensions меньше грузят приложения. Например: ставят промежуток опроса одна секунда(судя по всему, чтобы не синхронизировать коллекции по каждой мелочи, а синхронизировать кусками)

Comment: @Arantler, т.е. имеется ввиду не оптимизация самих `Reactive Extensions`, а оптимизация приложения при помощи `Reactive Extensions`, так? Выражайтесь яснее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Андрей скорее оптимизация использования Reactive Extensions. Грубо говоря, какие есть спободы "готовки".

Comment: А что их оптимизировать? Это как LINQ: вы просто выставляете Rx-интерфейс, а как их потребляют клиенты, вам по идее всё равно.

Comment: @VladD тобишь я правильно понимаю, что при работе с Reactive Extensions нет тонкостей, который повышают производительность Reactive Extensions и в следствии самой программы?

Comment: @Arantler: Ну, хм. Вот вы сможете сформулировать, какие тонкости есть при работе с _классами_, которые повышают производительность? Или там с _переменными_? Наверняка какие-нибудь есть.

Comment: @VladD ну, допустим для объектов, которые не нужны всегда и они достаточно большие, можно использовать Lazy обертку, что повышает производительность(ибо не загружается свойство всегда, даже когда не нужна). class хорошо использовать, если есть дерево данных, где есть класс Предок и 3 класса Дети. Детям нужно иметь данные о Предке. Если мы используем class, то это будет(может быть) один объект и 3 ссылки. Если struct, то это 3 объекта. Тем самым мы экономим память и пачка фишек.